# How to get actual date in typescript with Ionic 2

Tags: android, date, typescript, ionic2

I need get the actual date of device for print in my app , I'm using ionic 2 framework , I don't know how make this.

I need this in my typescript file , I try with diferent function but not working.

can I help me ? 
Thanks you very much! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please check the documentation before asking a question because this is a standard javascript feature:

```
let date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```